# Conflict using both memory_profiler and docopt

Tags: python, profiling

I have a Python program that uses docopt and appears to parse command-line arguments just fine.  However, when I attempt to include memory_profiler in the invocation (with -m memory_profiler), docopt fails to parse the command and prints the usage statement.  Here is a sample program:

```
"""
Usage:
  ids_transform [options]
  ids_transform --block BLOCK_MSG
  ids_transform --unblock
  ids_transform --version

Examples:
    ids_transform.py --block '2013-03-15 IM#123456 database down'
    ids_transform.py -c ../shared/etc/ids_transform.yaml

Options:
  -h --help                 show this help message and exit
  -c CONFIG --config=CONFIG config file
  -d --debug                begin debugging
  --force                   override block file; force run
  --profile                 use cProfile to gather statistics on process
"""

from docopt import docopt


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='1.0.0rc2')
    print(arguments)
```

Here is a successful invocation:

```
$ python ids.py -d --force -c foo.yml
{'--block': False,
 '--config': 'foo.yml',
 '--debug': True,
 '--force': True,
 '--help': False,
 '--profile': False,
 '--unblock': False,
 '--version': False,
 'BLOCK_MSG': None}
```

And here is the error when utilizing the memory_profiler:

```
$ python -m memory_profiler ids.py -d --force -c foo.yml
Usage:
  ids_transform [options]
  ids_transform --block BLOCK_MSG
  ids_transform --unblock
  ids_transform --version
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems memory_profiler doesn't strip itself from sys.argv, so a hack would (I guess) be to do it yourself:

```
if sys.argv[0].endswith('memory_profiler.py'):
    del sys.argv[0]
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  Thanks!

Comment: In the last version of memory_profiler (0.26) this bug was corrected